# Diode circuit fed with voltage follower doesnt work

Tags: operational-amplifier, buffer, circuit-design

[image]
I have a ldr circuit. In order to drive other circuits i connected a LDR circuit to voltage follower. I want to see at the output either nearly 0V or 9-12V. At Ltspice it works, but at the blackboard output remain same 9V. Yet, at the + pin of the voltage follower i see 9V or 0V. What do I need to connect in order voltage follower to work correctly?

Comment: Once U1 goes high, charge will remain 'stuck' between D1 and the + terminal on U2 since op-amps have high input impedance. When U1 shifts its output low, it can not pull the + terminal back down due to the diode?
I also do not understand what the diode is for...

Comment: @MadHatter - U1 is run open loop, and puts out either + or - 12 (assuming rail-to-rail operation, and since the op amps are not specified, this may not be possible). Then D1 will (he thinks) limit the -12 volt level to 0 volts.

Comment: Lm358 is the op-amp that i use. Diode is to limit -12v to 0v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could accomplish your goal by making R5 large (> 4.7k for the LM385 Op Amp to not be loaded to heavily.) and placing a diode from ground to the junction of R5 and the + terminal on U2. This would pull the -12 to ~0V and leave the +12 alone. The only issue is if this is working at high frequency > 1MHz, the parasitic capacitance of the diode could start to affect it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgAvmT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Are you sure your diode has correct polarity?

Comment: Yes, When the rail is pulled to -12, the diode will conduct and pull it up to ~ ground. The diode will not conduct when the rail is +12.

Comment: I tried it and i got 9v or -6v. 9v is ok but how can i prevent the negative voltage?

Comment: Your R5 is like 4.7K? What diode are you using? This should work... Try putting a load on the output of the last op-amp also...

Comment: Finally, i put 100k resistor and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wow that seems unnecessarily high, but I'm glad it works now. Odd that it needed to be 100k.